# VSCode Java Extension launch.json setup problems

Tags: java, json, visual-studio-code, launch, workspace

I can't seem to get the Workspace in VSCode for the Java Extension (Extension Pack by Microsoft) to work. It says my Mainclass of Test wouldn't exist, but there is the mainclass in Test , so  I think there has to be something wrong in the launch.json.

launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Debug (Launch)",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "mainClass": "Test",
        "args": ""
    }
]}
```

This is my structure (I know I shouldn't put code directly in the workspace, but it also doesn't work with folders...):

[image]

The Test.java file is just basic  "Hello World!".

Answer (score 0):

It is case sensitive. Also when you leave it empty, you get a 'popup' where you can select the right one.